# Google workspace account has been suspended with no recovery method

Tags: google-workspace

Many years ago I set up my domain so Google would manage my domain's email.  Today, possibly because I was accessing from another state, Google decides to suspend the service:

> Your organization's Google workspace account has been suspended. Please contact your Google workspace organization administrator to re-activate your organization.

So since I'm the administrator, I try to logon with those credentials, which are correct, but they challenge me, and want me to complete an email loop, but **the recovery email is in the locked domain!**

There seems to be no way to get this fixed. There's some code they can send me that I'm supposed to put my domain's server to prove I'm legit, but Google controls that...I have nothing on the domain except email. I'm paying Hover as the registrar.

Any way out?

I appreciate "Only Google can help", but there's no path forward. No phone number, no button to "open a ticket", no live chat. If you can't log on as administrator, none of that is available. How would a superuser get through on a problem like this?

There is a page that says:

> To get phone, chat, or email support for your legacy free account at xxxxxxx.com, you need to upgrade to Google Workspace.

> To continue, switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.

https://support.google.com/a

But I can't log in as administrator to upgrade my account so I can get support because when I log in with correct credentials, they send a challenge to an email address that's in the locked domain!

I can't be the only one this happened to, so figure they're just hiding the path to victory so they don't have to answer too many phone calls.  This page might be as close as I've gotten: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621

When I try to open a support case under my non-admin account, it says

> You do not have permission to create support cases.

I found a form to fill out: https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/disabled2

The above form accepts any email address, so you enter any email address that you currently have access to (not one that is locked, obviously).

But matter what I do, they want me to prove my identity by adding something to my domain.  I've asked Hover how to do this, but have not received a response yet.

Here's the email Google sent

> Your action is required in order for us to assist with your request.

> We were unable to verify the DNS ownership of Google Workspace Account sengsational.com. Please follow the instructions below to verify domain ownership.

> The following instructions outline the DNS record (CNAME or TXT) to add to your domain settings. Learn more

```
Via CNAME (preferred):
    Label/Host: [eight digit number removed]
    Destination/Target: google.com
    Time to live (TTL): 3600 seconds / 60 minutes / 1 Hour

For more information on how to create a CNAME record, please refer to the article Add a CNAME record to your domain's DNS records. If you need assistance creating the CNAME record, please contact your hosting provider for support.

You can verify your CNAME record here.

Via TXT:
    Label/Host: enter @ or leave it blank
    Value/Destination: google-gws-recovery-domain-verification=[eight digit number]
    Time to live (TTL): 3600 seconds / 60 minutes / 1 Hour

For more information on how to create a TXT record, please refer to the article Verify your domain with a TXT record . If you need assistance creating the TXT record, please contact your hosting provider for support.

You can verify your TXT record here.
```

> Note: Updates to DNS records may take 24-48 hours to propagate across the entire internet.
> In order for us to help you with the sign-up process, please follow this link and submit your request.
> Best regards,
> Google Workspace Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Key Finding:

Contact the company where you have your domain registered to have them manage the DNS records.

**Hover** is who I pay every year to keep my domain name active. I logged on, opened a chat, pasted-in the email from Google, and they were more than happy to update those records, *right there on the spot!*

Then, I went back to the email that Google sent me. To complete this authentication loop, there is a button on the page to re-check DNS.

After refreshing the page, I was provided the option to change the password. After I did that, I was logged into the gSuite administrator account, **finally!**"

They also automatically changed the recovery email to the one I was using that was outside the domain that was locked.

Comment: Not to kick a man after he's been down, but I'd like to point out the secondary learnings here:
* Recovery email should always be outside the system the recovery is for. It most likely says so on the form where you fill it in and this case is why.
* Cases like these are a good argument for keeping your domain hosting separate from your website, mail and other services. Worst case scenario, you can always prove ownership through DNS. For websites, if your webhoster gets DDOS'd, it is likely their DNS will get hammered as well and being able to divert to an alternative host can be useful.